# Local Notification using ios using swift

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification

I'm new in swift, I don't know how to implement local notification I have tried some code but it's not exactly work, so Anyone can help to implement local Notification in `iOS` using `swift`?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on google for this. Event Apple documentation can explain you how it works.

Comment: Take a look at [this Swift 3 example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45247943/4754881) for local notifications with [UNUserNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter).

Answer (score 36):

Here i am sharing example,

Register for local notification,

```
@IBAction func registerLocal(sender: AnyObject) {
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
}
```

Schedule local notification,

```
@IBAction func scheduleLocal(sender: AnyObject) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
    notification.alertBody = "Hey you! Yeah you! Swipe to unlock!"
    notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)


    guard let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings() else { return }

    if settings.types == .None {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Can't schedule", message: "Either we don't have permission to schedule notifications, or we haven't asked yet.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

}
```

It will fire local notification after `5 seconds`.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: `UILocalNotification` was deprecated. Would suggest using this: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unmutablenotificationcontent

Comment: 'UILocalNotification' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest

Comment: It is way easier to use my third party wrapper for Local notification in iOS. Just with 3 lines of code.
https://github.com/Salarsoleimani/SwiftLocalNotification

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of tutorials online for this, you could just Google it.

Here's a tutorial: http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/

Also here's an example of a local notification:

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = date
notification.alertBody = "Alert!"
notification.alertAction = "open"
notification.hasAction = true
notification.userInfo = ["UUID": "reminderID" ]
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: 'UILocalNotification' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest