# Swift ios triggering push notification inside the application and not through firebase console

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

Hello Good day everyone , i would just like to ask if how would it be possible to trigger push notification inside my ios app simply by let just say by clicking a button. My push notif is working fine sending through the firebase console but i have no idea making it possible inside the app . and also is alamofire applicable to that.
below is my app delegate code btw you can use it it can received message in foreground or background.

appdelegate

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//
//
//  Created by High Sierra User on 24/3/18.
//


import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate , UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            //            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn") {
            let  menuVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuCollectionViewController") as! MenuCollectionViewController

            let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: menuVC)
            nvc.navigationBar.isHidden =  true

            self.window?.rootViewController = nvc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        } else {

            self.showLoginScreen()
        }


        FirebaseApp.configure()

        let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert , UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let notificatiognSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes,categories : nil)

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificatiognSettings)

        return true
    }

    //    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    //                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    //                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    //        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    //
    //        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    //        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    //        // Print message ID.
    //        if let messageID = userInfo["gcmMessageIDKey"] {
    //            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    //        }
    //        print(userInfo)
    //
    //        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    //
    //
    //        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    //
    //    }


    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo["gcmMessageIDKey"] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        //            var badge = 0
        //            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        // completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo["gcmMessageIDKey"] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        switch response.actionIdentifier {
        case "action1":
            print("Action First Tapped")
        case "action2":
            print("Action Second Tapped")
        default:
            break
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        //        print("MessageID: \(userInfo["gcm_message_id"])")
        //        print(userInfo)

        if let message = userInfo["gcm_message_id"] {
            print("MessageID: \(message)")
        }

        print(userInfo)



    }

    func showLoginScreen()
    {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

        let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController)
        nvc.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        self.window?.rootViewController = nvc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }


    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "FridgeBoard")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()


    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {

                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: what you are looking for is termed as Local Notification in ios. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37324733/3548469